# MongoDB + Laravel fetch value if field exists in array otherwise fetch value from another field in array

Tags: mongodb, laravel, multilingual, jenssegers-mongodb

I am working with **laravel 5.3** and **jenssegers-mongodb**.

I have following document in MongoDB :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590fgfhddfgdfgdfgdg"),
    "name" : {
        "en" : "Meeting",
        "gu" : "બેઠક"
    },
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590fgfhddfgdfgdfgdg"),
    "name" : {
        "en" : "All",
    },
}
```

I would like to **fetch value if (name.gu) is exist,** otherwise **fetch from (name.en).**

**Is it possible ?**

Comment: jenssegers-mongodb has the worst documentation

Answer (score 0):

> Solution:

I was able to achieve his using `->whereNull(<column>)`

for me check if deleted column do not exists `->whereNull('deleted')`